# How to delete the row item from a view table after purchase is done?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

What I desire to achieve: I have a view where users can consult their payments inserting their ID. These payments will be displayed on a table, this table has a column with a "payment button". This button takes me to the "purchase page" (this url is external, and there is not connection between my site and that payment after button is pushed).

What I need is, once the payment is done, the user will be redirected to the "Approved payment page" on my site. Then when user search again the user's ID, that payment should not exist.

**My question**: How can I delete that payment row from the table if I don't have an established connection between my site and the payment site?